# How to get only text from element - Protractor Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, protractor

I am trying to get raw text only from a html element. For example:

```
<h1>This is a <br> Test</h1>
```

I want to be able to get the text inside `<h1>` minus the `<br>`....

`this is a Test`

I have tried:

`browser.driver.findElement(By.tagName('h1')).getAttribute('textContent');`

`browser.driver.findElement(By.tagName('h1')).getAttribute('innerHTML');`

`browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element(locator));`

I don't see any reason why `getAttribute('textContent')` isn't working, I think that would be the easiest way to get the raw text.

I know there have been some breaking changes with protractor for angular over the last few releases, that led me to use `browser.executeScript`.

**Update**

Please only post a solution if you have directly used it with protractor.

Comment: Use `.getText()`

Comment: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
element(by.css('h1')).getText().then((value: string) => {
    const val: string = value.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
});
```

A handy [cheatsheet for protractor](https://gist.github.com/javierarques/0c4c817d6c77b0877fda).

And will highlight what Andrew Lohr posted. Always check the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) :)

Comment: `getText()` should work, but the return text will includes a new line,because the `br` tag. So you need to remove the new line like  `element(by.(xxx)).getText().then(function(txt){ return txt.replace(/\s{2,}/, ' ');});`

Comment: Yeap makes sense. Thanks. Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer's so far have not addressed getting just the text without `<br>`.

Yong's response was what led me down the path to find the solution.

For those interested. The most simple way is to get the text and use `replace` to switch the `<br>` with a space instead.

```
    element(by.(xxx)).getText().then(function(text) { 
      text = text.replace(replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," "); 
      console.log(text);
    });
```

Comment: aweome! i have been trying to get text and then return the text to function caller.